# How retrieve foreign key with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a foreign key called `sectorId` in my `AspNetUsers` entity, I can insert the `sectorId` key, but when I get the key it is as if it were null. How can I get this data correctly?

My `Setor` class:

```
public class Setor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

My `User` class:

```
public class Usuario : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public Setor Setor { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext` class:

```
public class SSContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
    public SSContext(DbContextOptions<SSContext> opts, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(opts)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
  
    public DbSet<Unidade> Unidades { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Setor> Setores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

The data

[image]

I want to do a join but the result of my query is always null

```
var query = await (from u in _context.Usuarios 
                   where u.UserName == User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
                   select u.Setor.Id).ToListAsync();
return Content($"{query.Count}");
```

Comment: if you remove the where, what's the result then?

Comment: Most probably you where clause fails for every record in `Usarios` table. Or returned entity doesn't refernce any `Setor`. Also, it would be easier in use if you defined foreign key on your class with two propeties: navigation property of type `Setor` and foreign key as `int SetorId`, then you don't need to join in your query :)

Comment: Thanks Stefan. if i use "User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)" to get my username directly in the query i get  ArgumentOutOfRangeException, but when i store findFIrst in variable and put in the query i get the expected result.

Comment: Michal, Could you explain more, as an aswer ?